# Network manager indicator missing

Tags: 12.04, indicator, network-manager

I recently upgraded from 11.10 to 12.04. My first attempt failed, and I received an error stating that not all of the required packages were downloaded. Before (successfully) attempting again, I noticed that there was no longer a networking indicator in the upper panel. The indicator did not reappear with the installation of 12.04.

To be clear, my wireless connection has experienced no problems, despite the missing indicator.

Here are the solutions that I have found which *did not* work for me:

1. Editing `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and replacing `[ifupdown] managed=false` with `=true`.
2. Reinstalling `network-manager` (via `apt-get install --reinstall`).

I am currently running 12.04 on an Asus Eee PC 1005 HA, and I am new to seeking solutions through forums, so I apologize if I have neglected to provide some vital information about my hardware.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Motivated by [this post on Ubuntuforums.org](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1907529), I have found a solution to my issue in two steps.

1. Purge and reinstall `network-manager-gnome`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge network-manager-gnome && sudo apt-get install network-manager-gnome
   ```
2. Add `nm-applet` to the Startup Applications (which may be found by entering "Startup Applications" in the Dash and setting the path to `/usr/bin/nm-applet`).

   I verified that the latter step was necessary, as the indicator did not appear after login without this addition of `nm-applet` to the Startup Applications.

Comment: thanks! finally learned the name of that applet! i installed network-indicator for some dumb reason, and it removed the network-manager-gnome... and i'm clueless to the unintuitive magic required to get apt-get removed package history... after reinstalling this one all is back to normal. Also, had to reboot before nm-applet stopped dying with errors. think it also installed some services, but i didn't take note.

Comment: Thank you! I have had several problems with WiFi and not it's working perfect (so far)!

Comment: Only needed to do the first step, then relog

Comment: Did not help on ubuntu 14.04 64bit

Comment: Finally. I need to look at so many places and did all the dumb things like installing network indicator etc. But this is the solution.

Answer (score 5):

if everything else fails,use this

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-applet-complete
```

quick restart and you should see it on the panel again

Comment: This helped me on Ubuntu 14.04 64bit

Comment: This helped me on Ubuntu 15.04 65 bit. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The only solution that worked for me was:

```
sudo apt install indicator-applet indicator-network
```

Source: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2251198&page=2&p=13167056#post13167056

Answer (score 0):

For me the answer into plasma desktop or KDE was into the system tray settings -> General -> network enabled and then in Entries -> show