# how do I fix and connect my wifi to a new wireless I am using?

Tags: wireless

My wifi connection has stopped working and I'd like to connect to a new wifi that I have but there's no where I can find a place to fix that and or how to go about fixing it, please help and Im fairly new to Ubuntu.

Comment: Could you provide more info about your WiFi hardware if you changed anything lately?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Answer (score 0):

In the topbar you can see a little icon for your network settings. Clicking that icon gives you the option to connect to another wireless network. Clicking Edit Connections gives you to edit your current connection or connections you've made in the past.

[image]

You can also hit the Windows button on your keyboard and typ network. Depening on what you have installed you will get applications to edit the networks too.

Comment: I used to have that network icon on my above panel on my screen where I saved all my shortcuts to acces my most used apps from. Once, there there used to be that network icon and the bluetooth one but they're gone now for some reason. I do not know how to find it and or put it back there... I've gone through the settings and the preferences too but I don't think it's picking up the local wireless in the area I've located to....

Is there a way to fix it through the terminal? (codes etc)

Comment: Even when you're not connected you should have an icon here.It seems there is something else going on. Does this other question help you out: http://askubuntu.com/questions/159812/network-manager-indicator-missing?

Can't you find network in your launcher?