# Wireless indicator disappeared on Ubuntu 14.04 and can not connect to new wifi

Tags: 14.04, networking, network-manager, indicator

Strangely, wireless indicator has been disappeared. In addition, When I open the network manager, I can not connect to new wifi, so, I am only able to connect to previous connected wifis.
Any Help to get it back?

Comment: May be related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/503982/why-dont-i-see-network-manager-icon-on-the-gnome-top-bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what is missing is that the program `nm-applet` is not running, try starting it in a shell, with just:

```
nm-applet
```

or add it to the tray somehow.
If it is just started like this, I'm not sure it will stay when you reboot, but it should work for now at least.