# Accidentally removed home .config directory recursively and forcefully? Help me

Tags: command-line, networking, unity, indicator

On Ubuntu 16.04, I ran this command on terminal:

```
sudo rm -rf ~/.config
```

After this top taskbar is removed, and I can't go anywhere. So, I reboot system from the terminal which was already opened.

After reboot, system boots fine. I have noticed that chrome was removed and there is no wifi indicator on taskbar.

So, I reinstall chrome and ran few commands like

```
killall unity-panel-service
sudo service network-manager restart
sudo apt-get install indicator-applet indicator-network
```

to get it back, but nothing.. except I installed chrome again and all logins and history was not removed. (I wonder why those didn't removed with chrome)

And now I'm unable to connect to any other wifi network from System Settings > Network > Wireless.

Solution I need is, wifi indicator back and I should able to connect to other network as I was able to do before..

Comment: You might want to have a look at [`safe-rm`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/safe-rm) package, it helps greatly preventing accidental deletions like that.

Comment: @dessert Solution I need is, wifi indicator back and I should able to connect to other network as I was able to do before..

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: What was your intent when you deleted .config? Were you intending to loose desktop configurations and start over? You figured out the hard way you can't simply delete this directory.

Comment: I suppose to delete .coby file in same dir. I don't know what I was thinking I quickly tab to auto complete the file name and hit enter, and before I realise what I did, Everything is doomed :/

Comment: Do you know if your home partition is separate from your root partition?

Comment: I think NO! bcoz sudo fdisk -l shows three partitions (Boot 458GB, Extended 8GB, Swap 8GB). I didn't manually partition at installation time. it's was done automatically by installer.

Comment: you could just have a trash folder in your home directory so if you want to do something crazy like this can just do: mv .config trash. That way you can always mv it back.

Comment: I'm asking because the .config contains a lot of user data. You might come back later wondering where a lot of other configurations and settings went as well.

Comment: @HermannIngjaldsson Thanks for you suggestion keep that in mind next time ;)..

Comment: @jdwolf I didn't face any other issue for now, and I have restart ubuntu severals times, this problem happen yesterday.

Comment: Add the output of `ls -la ~/.config`

Comment: .          dconf          gtk-2.0           nautilus         user-dirs.dirs
..         evolution      gtk-3.0           pulse            user-dirs.locale
autostart  gedit          ibus              unity            user-share
Code       gnome-session  libaccounts-glib  update-notifier
compiz-1   google-chrome  Mist              upstart

Comment: sorry cant post with -l flag, as it extends comment limit.

Comment: @luser: You can [edit] your question to include the information which was asked for. Please do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figure out the solution from another thread (https://askubuntu.com/a/530958/773953), which helped me, +1 to them.

SOLUTION:

[ STEP 1 ]

```
sudo apt install network-manager-gnome
```

Install network manager, which might have removed with .config directory like chrome.

```
nm-applet
```

Run Applet, network indicator should popup by now.

If you can notice, exiting terminal will remove the indicator. So, you have to add it in Startup Applications.

[ STEP 2 ]

Search and run "Startup Applications" in Ubuntu search.

[Startup Applications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQdoO.png)

Click on Add and write `nm-applet` in Command field, and Add it.

[Startup Apps Dialog Popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1Hlw.png)

[Write nm-applet in Command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ofmU.png)

Close the dialog popup and reboot you Ubuntu.
And it should always be on there(top bar) for YOU.

Answer (score 1):

Because files in /home aren't managed by the package manager reinstalling them won't do anything.

.config contains a lot of files related to the users desktop configuration and application configurations.

.config primarily is configuration for applications where data (like for example your emails if you're using evolution) are stored in .local.

Applications rely on config files it created in .config to work as expected. Some applications may recreate the configs in .config if they are missing but others probably won't if they still see files in .local.

While deleting .config shouldn't break anything it appears to with unity. The configurations are likely not in a default state but a zeroed state.

The culprit seems to be that the indicator applets are suppose to be in Startup Applications but no longer are. Search for Startup Applications in settings and add

Comment: Add example please: like "name", "Command", "Comment"

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling `network-manager`

```bsh
sudo apt-get install network-manager # if it was removed
```

or install the indicator applet

```bsh
sudo apt-get install indicator-applet indicator-network
```

Comment: reinstalling network-manager will automatically pop indicator or I have to reboot after its complete.

Comment: And I have already tried install indicator applet before, nothing.