# My list of available wifi connections has gone

Tags: networking, iphone

I was facing some problem (connection from iPhone hotspot) so I installed *wicd network manager* but that was not of any good so I unistalled it but then tray icon of networks has gone. I talked about something as shown in image.

Now luckily usb connection from iPhone is working fine. Earlier it used to give problem. Sometime it could connect easily sometime it does not.

But I don't know how to select from other available wifi connections.

I want to restore as shown in image. Also, I want to restore ethernet. Mine is realtek hardware.

[image: Network]

Comment: Knowing what you actually did instead of *"I installed a package but that was not of any good so I unistalled it"* may help. Please edit and describe what you tried, what you installed.

Answer (score 0):

I need to run marathon. I was not having enough idea of what I need so search took time. Tried some commands. But finally, problem is solved. I suppose, everything got better.

I used this [link](https://askubuntu.com/a/593015/118354) for network stability and then this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159812/network-manager-indicator-missing?rq=1) to get network manager indicator at System Tray. It is an applet.